# Salesforce: CanvasApp integration

Tags: visualforce, integration, canvas, website-integration

How can you implement/integrate with web-site (third party) without using oAuth and I know that by enabling oAuth you can define the callback url and all good but I'm in a situation that third party application does not have the capability to handle oAuth in that case what should be my approach for the Canvas App?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Iframe it ...Thats it ..Canvas asks for some code and work from other end .If not you just iframe it .Looks hackish but thats all you can do

Comment: my understanding was you have two options when it comes to canvas app, signed request and oauth? is that not correct?

Comment: i'm looking here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_authentication.htm

Comment: That's correct but for signed request you still need some work on other end ..

Comment: Nick, do you have an explicit requirement that it must be a Canvas app? Could you use a [Web Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_web_tabs.htm) instead?

Comment: Ya use signed request and the other party still needs some work.

Comment: @MarkPond: yes i do, and the requirement is 1) salesforce will pass the data to the website 2) webiste will pass the data back to salesforce

Comment: @MohithShrivastava: for the signed request steps to create for connected apps are same? if you like to answer as a separate which is fine for me and i can create another question related with that if you say so.

Comment: @NickKahn Yes steps are same .Create same connected app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas App Implementation supports Signed Request .Using Signed request ,the client end app can verify the request .

This will still needs some work on the other end to verify the signed request using the consumer secret generated from the connected app.

Else if you dont need user identification , a simple iframe or web tab should help

Comment: okay i did changed it to `signed request` and unchecked the oAuth and now throwing me an error if i unchecked the oAuth setting `Oops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application [external_App_Local].
Force.com Canvas can not locate an installed canvas app with the namespace [] and API name [external_App_Local].`  yes the error is very obvious that its not finding my canvas app but i have triple check the api_name and its exact the same but not sure why its throwing me this error. also if i Check the oAuth back then the error is not throwing... making me crazy

Comment: You still need the oauth setting .You may not go through oauth flow but keep it .So the oauth URL is same as the canvas URL

Comment: oh interesting.... so in other words i have been doing 'signed request' not the oAuth

Comment: Yes .So in oauth you redirect back the user to login of SFDC and if user is logged in ,here will explicitly approve for the first time and confirm the access to the SFDC